# How to create own format using Maven Assembly Plugin

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-plugin, pom.xml, maven-assembly-plugin

I have gone through the creation of zip,tar,jar etc format using maven assembly plugin. But i want to create my own format (say .cba) extn. Is it possible to do this by using this plugin???

In the official plugin page ,it's mentioned like this

Currently it can create distributions in the following formats:

zip
tar
tar.gz
tar.bz2
jar
dir
war
and **any other format that the ArchiveManager has been configured for**

So i want to make the output as say **abc.cba** (like abc.zip,abc.jar etc)

I can't directly give the .cba or cba as in format tag,it's getting error

Can anyone help me how to do this . Thanks a lot in advance,as i am stuck with this

Comment: First: Why do you like to create a different format? What is the purpose? Just cause you would like to or is there any serious reason behind it? Furthermore why does zip etc. not fit?

Comment: @khmarbaise Thanks for the response...I want to create an OSGI bundle,so i used maven-bundle-plugin for that and the bundle need to be in the extension of Composite Bundle Archive(**.cba** extension say abac.cba) which contains a jar and a META_INF folder. I have made this structure using bundle plugin. I want to be in that format for my project purpose. So how to do this using maven assembly plugin

Comment: What not continue to use maven-bundle-plugin ?

Comment: The closest might be using shared assemblies: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/sharing-descriptors.html

Comment: @khmarbaise Maven Bundle plugin allows me to create this structure,that's fine what i mentioned is i want to make this bundle extension as .cba, if we use bundle plugin,the target folder contains the jar file and META-INF folder,but i want these two in an extension say abc.cba contains jar and meta-inf

Answer (score 0):

The `maven-assembly-plugin` has formats already defined and unfortunately you cannot add another one. If what you need is just the zip renamed with another extension name, you can add an execution of the `maven-antrun-plugin` that will change the extension name of the generated file, and to ensure that you have the same name between the two plugins use a property in the pom in which you set the name.